# How to read word by word in text field?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a program that translates text into sign language using Unity 3D. My program has a text field where the user can type a word to translate it into sign but currently I am only able to read 1 word at a time. How can I read the next word and the next after that in the text field ? Now can only read for example "name". But i need the system to able to read for example "my name is BOB" where the system read "my" first and call the sign .. then read "name" second and call the sign .. and then read "is" and call sign.. I need looping coding that able to accept unlimited word in the textfield.

This is my code for textfield :

```
var stringToEdit : String = "Type here to search";
var object : GameObject;
var lower : String;
var upper : String;
var showtext : GUIText ;
var showtext1 : GUIText ;

 var anim : Animation;

  function OnGUI () {
         // Make a text field that modifies stringToEdit.
          stringToEdit = GUI.TextField (Rect (30, 10, 200, 20),      stringToEdit, 25);

    if (Event.current.keyCode == KeyCode.Return)
    {
            lower = stringToEdit.ToLower ();
             upper = stringToEdit.ToUpper ();

             anim = object.animation;

                     if(anim.GetClip(lower))
                     {
                        object.animation.Play(lower);
                        showtext.text = upper;  

                    }

                     else
                     {
                     showtext1.text = "Text could not be found!";
                     object.animation.Play("idle");

    }

        }
        if (!object.animation.IsPlaying(lower)&& !object.animation.IsPlaying("idle")){
        showtext.text = "";
        showtext1.text = "";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split()`

First take the whole text in a String then split it.

```
String str = "my name is BOB";
String[] res = str.split(" ");.
```

The res will be an array with the values:

my,name,is,BOB